# Detach thing from AWS IoT Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-iot, aws-sdk-go-v2

I am trying to delete AWS IoT certificates for a Thing. I am using aws-sdk-go-v2. From documentation I understood that to delete certificates, we must: 1) detach policy 2) detach thing
3) set certificate as inactive and then 4) delete certificates.

I am able to detach policy(DetachPolicy), deactivate certificate(UpdateCertificate), But unable to detach thing. To detach thing I am using [DetachThingPrincipal](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/iot@v1.27.0#Client.DetachThingPrincipal) method. In doc its mentioned that its an asynchronous API. Normally to handle Async APIs we use goroutines and channels to fetch data whenever response is ready. But in this case it seems that it is handled internally. So I have simply invoked the method as a normal function.

```
if op, err := iotClient.DetachThingPrincipal(context.TODO(), &iot.DetachThingPrincipalInput{
        Principal: aws.String(credInfo["certfARN"]),
        ThingName: aws.String(deviceId),
    }); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: [deleteCreds] - Unable to detach thing:", err.Error())
        return err
    }
```

As a response I don't get any error and next I invoke **DeleteCertificate** method. The method throws **"Things must be detached before deletion"** error. How can this issue be fixed ?

As it may take time to detach thing should I add a wait timer of few seconds and then try to delete certificate ?

Comment: In Javascript there are options like async/await or callback mechanism to wait till the async process is completed and then invoke further steps. You may have to find out equivalent in Go. You cant hardcode wait time.   Like https://hackernoon.com/asyncawait-in-golang-an-introductory-guide-ol1e34sg

Answer (score 0):

I know you may need a Go code..
But I have a equivalent code in Javascript, you could do similar

The main essence is it works on async/await once the detach completes it then carry on.

```
/**
 * Detach the given certificate from the given Thing 
 * 
 * @param thingName 
 * @param certificateArn 
 * @returns 
 */
export const detachCertificateFromThing = async (thingName: string, certificateArn: string) => {

  const detachThingPrincipalRequest: DetachThingPrincipalRequest = {
    thingName,
    principal: certificateArn
  }
  const result = await iot.detachThingPrincipal(detachThingPrincipalRequest).promise()
  return result
}
```

And to use the above helper, you would do like this

```
 // detach certificate from thing
 const detachCertificateResponse = await detachCertificateFromThing(thingName, certificateArn)
 console.log(`Certificate ARN: ${certificateArn} detach from thing: ${thingName}, response: ${JSON.stringify(detachCertificateResponse)}`);
```